# Iphone:how to create json in Objective c

Tags: iphone, json

I am working on iPhone App.I have to return json string to a webservice in following format from Iphone.I am using Objective-C

```
{
"InspectionDetails":
    [
        {"isCompleted":"Y","QMSStepId":"1A","QMSEmpId":"6","QMSInspectionID":"1","InspectedDate":"07/28/11 09:52:34",       "isNewRoom":"1","RoomInspID":"1","QMSRoomId":"1","QMSScoreId":"4"},
        {"isCompleted":"Y","QMSStepId":"1B","QMSEmpId":"4","QMSInspectionID":"1","InspectedDate":"07/28/11 09:52:34",       "isNewRoom":"1","RoomInspID":"1","QMSRoomId":"1","QMSScoreId":"3"}
    ],
"InspectionComments":
    [
        {"QMSPredefinedCommentId":"1","customText":"Test1 Comment","RoomInspID":"1"},
        {"QMSPredefinedCommentId":"2","customText":"Test2 Comment","RoomInspID":"1"}
    ],
"Tools":
    [
        {"Facility_Code" : "1","HddId" : "AIPH01"}
    ]
}
```

can any one please help me how can I form the above response?

I have an idea that I can do this by using NSArray and NSDictonary but I want all the arrays in one dictionary. Can anyone please guide?

Thanks,
Shradha

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use something like [SBJSON](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/).  Then you can just do

```
NSString *jsonString = [myDictionary JSONRepresentation];
```

Comment: Hi cduhn.But i have 3 dictionary objects.From above string you can see One for "InspectionDetails",one for "InspectionComments" and one for "Tools".Can i come this 3 dictionary objects in one and use JsonValue.how can i?

Comment: That's just 1 dictionary object containing 3 arrays.  Just call `JSONRepresentation` on the top level dictionary.  It will recursively serialize all the objects in that dictionary into their JSON representations.

Comment: Hi cduhn.Sorry but i have to form the json string in above format.
my query is how will i be able to create the json string in above format from 3 array. .i have 3 seperate array with keys and create a dictionary from it. .can u help pls?

Comment: Oh.  For that you can just do `NSDictionary *inspectionDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:inspectionDetailsArray, @"InspectionDetails", inspectionCommentsArray, @"InspectionComments", toolsArray, @"Tools", nil];`.  Then call `JSONRepresentation` on that dictionary.

Comment: Thank You so much  cduhn for ur help.I really appreciate it.It saved my time.Even i was thinking of dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys and tried but was not aware of syntax proplery.Thanks you so much

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using JSONKit (https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit), it works very well and is speedy enough to serve common needs.

Suppose you have a NSDictionary like:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
                        [NSArray arrayWithObjects:,@"anotherDict",@"anotherDict1",@"anotherDict" nil] 
forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Key1",@"Key2",@"Key3", nil]];
```

then you can simply get your JSON representation as follows: `NSString *jsonString = [dict JSONString]`.

Read the documentation to get additional features.